# Implementing avatarImageWithUserInitials in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I need to implement `avatarImageWithUserInitials` from the JSQMessages framework. However it appears to only be implemented in Objective-C

The documentatiojn is located at: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.3/Classes/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.html#//api/name/avatarImageWithUserInitials:backgroundColor:textColor:font:diameter:

At present, there does not appear to be a way to implement this feature in swift.

How can I add this feature into my swift app?

Answer (score 0):

you can check out a full implementation here. https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1606

and it will be apart of the Swift Example project soon.

But the basic rundown is you need to make an avatar object which can be done like this.

```
let AvatarLeonard = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithUserInitials("DL", backgroundColor: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor(), textColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
```

also this option:

```
// Create avatar with Placeholder Image
 let AvatarJobs = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImageWithPlaceholder(UIImage(named: "Jobs"), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
```

sorry this has taken so long.

Comment: The example project is now apart of the main project.